# onclick button doesnt apply filter to a crossfilter dimension

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, crossfilter

I've been searching for options but still I dont make it work so I hope somebody can help me out.
Im creating a input field with a button, the idea is to select one option from the list and then the button search will use the value to filter my crossfilter dimension and update my table.

My send button is like this

```
<input onclick="javascript:dimListDimension(document.getElementById('compList').value);" type="button" value="Search">
```

But in my table is not applying the filter because I get this error ReferenceError: dimListDimension is not defined but it is defined.

I hope someone to help me on how I can make this work...

The full code is in https://jsfiddle.net/ichwalrus/zhut332g/

Comment: Your fiddle has 404s

Comment: I updated the link, the code there is only to show how Im using the onclick event and my dimension

Comment: It is still full of errors.

Comment: Try serving your external resources from a CDN. Start here: https://cdnjs.com/

Comment: I dont see the errors, you can see it better here https://orionhub.org/file/ichwalrus-OrionContent/test/main.html

Comment: I can't see that without logging in.